# Typo3 8.7.x Extbase: Frontent User Login not working

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

I want to login the frontend user, but it is only working in addition with the following line.

```
setcookie('fe_typo_user', $session, NULL, "/");
```

my code:

```
//$user = Frontent User Object
$tsfe = $GLOBALS['TSFE'];
$tsfe->fe_user->checkPid = 0;
$info = $tsfe->fe_user->getAuthInfoArray();
$userdata = $tsfe->fe_user->fetchUserRecord($info['db_user'], $user->getUsername()); 
$tsfe->fe_user->createUserSession($userdata);
//I read somewhere that would fix a bug
$tsfe->fe_user->setAndSaveSessionData('dummy', TRUE);
$tsfe->loginUser = 1;
$session = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['ses_id'];
//not working?!
//$tsfe->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'fe_typo_user', $session);           
//only working with this additional line
setcookie('fe_typo_user', $session, NULL, "/");
```